# C# ListView prevent selection

Tags: c#

I'm in a situation with a multiple select ListView where a maximum of three items may be selected.  I currently have following code

```
    private void grassListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string landType = this.grassLandTypeComboBox.Text;
        if (this.grassListView.SelectedIndices.Count < 4)
        {
            ArrayList selectedGrassTextures = (ArrayList)((Hashtable)this.paintGrass[landType])["textures"];
            selectedGrassTextures.Clear();
            foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in this.grassListView.SelectedItems)
            {
                selectedGrassTextures.Add(listViewItem.Text);
            }
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("You cannot have more than 3 grasses selected for any given attribute type");
        }
    }
```

this code works and in the end my selectedGrassTextures HashTable has only three elements.  However the GUI still shows the element as (selected/focused?).  So to the user it seems that it is still selected.  So I like to prevent this, is there anything I can use to either find the last element clicked on and put the selection of it or the focus.  Another way would be if there is an event Before SelectedIndexChanged that I can move my < 4 check into.  Is there such an event, I thought ListView.SelectedIndexChanging, but in my IDE it shows up as not existing.  I'm using visual studio express and framework 3.5, can't use 4.5 for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the ItemSelectionChanged event:

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 4) e.Item.Selected = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this seemed the right way to go however

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type .'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs'.  

So I'm guessing this is not in framework 3.5 or I'm missing something

Comment: Hm, should be, according to the MSDN documentation. Are you binding it to the right event?

Comment: this.grassListView.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.grassListView_SelectedIndexChanged); this is my binding but hmmm are there different EventHandlers for different Controls or is it always System.EventHandler ?  I'm a java dev so some of this stuff confuses me enourmously

Comment: Yup, this is the wrong one; this binds the new code to the old handler of the SelectionIndexChanged event. You should doubleclick on the ItemSelectionChanged event in the designer and you will get a additional event block with a different and more helpful e parameter, which includes a reference to the item in question.

Comment: aha that makes sense I was just walking through the msdn again myself, and spotted it.  is the IndexChanged one deprecated or something and should I always use ItemSelectionChanged ?

Comment: no, they coexist and are defined slightly different although atm I couldn't explain what the difference is..

Comment: well it worked like a charm now, my next challenge is preventing the SelectedIndexChanged to trigger when I do a grassListView.Items.Clear() somewhere in the code ... this is going to be a fun one as well.  I can do it with a flag boolean but that leaves me feeling so dirty ... in java I at least can give extra params to my event to say if it's from the code or from the GUI ...

Comment: when I need to make this distinction I usually can leave the first param (sender) as null  (or maybe both) when I trigger an event programatically. One can also have a look at the e members of the event argument and see if there is a member which lends itself to pass in special info.  But as you don't trigger it yourself but it is triggered yb the Clear this won't do. What do you need to prevent in the SelectionIndexChanged code?

Comment: If you really want to you could remove it from the handler before the Clear and add it back afterwards. Just copy the line from the designer.cs and add it before and after the clear and change the first one from `+=` to `-=`

Comment: I'm using the same control to fill up multiple HashTables with selected items.  However when I change a combobox to indicate another HashTable, and then want to put the allready selected items in the ListView I programaticaly clear the current items selected in the ListView and then I don't want the select code to run.  I did it like you said and it seems to work perfectly.  this.grassListView.ItemSelectionChanged -= this.grassListView_ItemSelectionChanged;

 and this.grassListView.ItemSelectionChanged += new ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler(this.grassListView_ItemSelectionChanged);

Comment: As you said that you are new to c# allow me to add two final notes on the technique of removing and re-adding to an eventhandler:

As the syntax implies more than one event can be bound to a handler. The one removed and re-added will move to the last place in the queue.

More likely a problem sometimes: If the stuff in-beteween fails you either crash or jump to an error-eventhandler; so if that seems possible at all it would be a good idea to wrap it in a try block and put the re-adding line in a finally clause. Cheers, t

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind, to bad those handlers aren't part of a linked list, at least you could choose your node where to put it.  In principle C# is just a language as any other, but to me it feels like java is way more simplified in some aspects of programming

Comment: Well, it is a nice laguage and still growing. Hejlsberg of Turbo Pascal fame designed it, right after completing the MS Java compiler. So he made some decisions that clearly were influenced by that experience..